# iOS push notifications can be sent with certificate-based connection but token-based connection returns DeviceTokenNotForTopic

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to set up iOS push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Apple suggests two approaches for setting up server connection to APNs:

1. Certificate-based
2. Token-based

Token-based authentication is recommended so I tried it first (by generating a token key `.p8` file and adding it to Firebase project settings for the app). But the notification wasn't sent to any of the devices that were successfully registered and received device tokens as well as FCM tokens.

I also tried to use the [Push Notifications](https://github.com/onmyway133/PushNotifications) app (as described in [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started)) instead of Firebase Console for sending out the notification. This is what I got when I used `.p8` token key:

```
Failed: DeviceTokenNotForTopic
```

However, if I generate `APNs Development iOS` certificate specifically for my app's bundle ID and configure Firebase (as well as this Push Notifications app) to use generated `.p12` certificate, everything works fine - notifications are sent to all registered devices both through Firebase and through the Push Notifications app.

Any ideas what I may have missed in my configuration for token-based connections?